# How can I provide subclass-specific methods to call on an instance of baseclass?

Tags: c#, visitor-pattern

Trivially, if I have a base-class and several sub-classes which all implement the same method signature, I can do the following:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
 public abstract int GetValue();
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
 public override int GetValue() => 123;
}
...

class MyClass
{
 public void SomeMethod()
 {
  BaseClass o = ...;
  var i = o.GetValue();
 }
}
```

But what if I want to provide subclass-specific logic *outside* the subclass (perhaps a Visitor pattern or something)? You cannot do the following because it involves a conversion, you have to know *which* type 'o' is:

```
class MyClass
{
 public void SomeMethod()
 {
  BaseClass o = ...;
  int i = CalculateSomething(o);
 }

 private int CalculateSomething(SubClass o)
 {
  return 999;
 }
}
```

Is there an obvious workaround in code or design that doesn't involve explicitly checking the type?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to overwrite method `GetValue` or are you trying to use generics? What should `MyClass.GetValue` return? Should `MyClass.GetValue` accept different types as parameter? You can use `BaseClass` as parameter and check if the passed instance is of type `SubClass`

Comment: "You can use BaseClass as parameter and check if the passed instance is of type SubClass" - that's exactly what I want to avoid, otherwise it's easy. I think actually, this might be the exact problem Visitor pattern tries to fix

Comment: Use base.GetValue()

Comment: To clarify I am not trying to wrap or base class method. Rather, the logic is being removed from the class into some other entity (like a Command or Visitor). My first code is only to highlight the comaprison

Comment: If you could provide a concrete example that uses type checking, we would have a better idea of what effect you want to achieve and perhaps how to avoid the type checking.

Comment: What if somebody does `class MysteryClass : BaseClass {}` and then calls `SomeMethod()` with an instance of `MysteryClass`? The abstract pattern addresses this by requiring `MysteryClass` to specify an override for `GetValue()`, but the external version does not.

Comment: Without knowing what `CalculateSomething` does: You want to call it using an instance of `BaseClass` (whatever the concrete type is at runtime) and you want it to vary depending on that concrete type. That tells me to look for some way to put that functionality in `BaseClass` and its subclasses.